# how can I use custom extenstion/widget in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I use gii to generate a extension in yii2.0, here is the code

namespace ms\editor;

```
/**
 * This is just an example.
 */
class AutoloadExample extends \yii\base\Widget
{
    public function run()
    {
        return "Hello!";
    }
}
```

when I want to use it in my view file,

```
use ms\editor\AutoloadExample;
...
<?= AutoloadExample::widget();?>
```

I use yii2 baisic template, and I put the "ms" folder in "vendor" folder, but it just tell me class ms\editor\AutoloadExample not found, what should I to make yii2 to find the class?is there something like "components"or "extension" folder in yii1.1?
can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your widget should inherit the CWidget class and place the widget in components.

```
public class AutoloadExample extends CWidget 
{
   public function run() { }
}
```

You can then run the widget in your view like this;

```
$this->widget('application.components.AutoloadExample', array('your variables'));
```

Comment: It doesn't work in yii 2, it can only work in yii 1, thanks all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Would you try one such?
for example create a file in "app/frontend/widgets/"

File Name : **Deneme.php**

```
<?php

namespace frontend\widgets;

class Deneme
{

    static function yazdir () {

    echo 'asd';

    }

}
```

To use;

```
use frontend\widgets\Deneme;

Deneme::yazdir();
```

Comment: I have try this, but it also says "class not found".

Comment: What type is your yii 2? Advanced or basic?